# Event listener for html5 details node state change

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, mutation-events

I am trying to add an event listener to detect a change in the state of an HTML5 details node.

Initially I tried attaching a listener to the open and close events as it makes logical sense to me for a details node to have those listeners, but it doesn't and I do not see any mention of them in the html5 spec.

I tried (in Google Chrome) the change event, since the html5 spec (and Inspect Element confirms) that the way to open and close details is to add/remove the open attribute. I was hoping that the node gaining/losing an attribute would trigger the change event, but apparently it does not.

How the hell do I trigger a script action off of the changing of state of a details node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using the `DOMAttrModified` [mutation event](http://help.dottoro.com/lagstsiq.php/#MutationEvent_Members)?

Comment: $('details').bind('DOMAttrModified', function(e) {alert('triggered'); }); does nothing (but binding to click does, but binding to click does not check if another js function opens/closes the details node)

Comment: It seems Chrome does not support DOMAttrModified

Comment: DOMSubtreeModified works! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Listening to DOMAttrModified works for many browsers, and DOMSubtreeModified works for Chromium based browsers, but nowadays there's a more specific event available to listen for on [details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) nodes:

You can add a listener/handle the [toggle event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDetailsElement/toggle_event) for the `details` node when you want to detect the `details` node is opened or closed.
So the opening or closing of the details' node contents cannot be cancelled.

This example selects the first `details` node it can find in a document. Think about some other query selector, or `document.querySelectorAll('details')` or even some js framework to set the event on multiple `details` nodes (i.e. `$('details').on('toggle', <function here>)`.

```
document.querySelector('details').addEventListener('toggle', 
    function afterToggle(e) { 
        if(e.target.open){
            //do something when opened
        }
        else {
            //do something when closed
        }
    }
);
```